# Where to find documentation for Nintex Workflow web service?

Tags: nintex-workflow

Where do I find documentation for Nintex Workflow web service?

The webservice can be found under `http://myservername/MyNintexSite/_vti_bin/nintexworkflow/workflow.asmx`, but the methods require parameters and I cannot find description, what those parameters are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of [Nintex Workflow 2007 SDK](http://connect.nintex.com/files/folders/sdk/entry122.aspx) there is a file `Nintex Workflow 2007 SDK 1.2.pdf`.
At the end of this file (pages 131-186) is the documentation of Web Service